# Unable to connect to wifi using wifi package in flutter

Tags: flutter, wifi, android-wifi, flutter-dependencies

I am developing an app in flutter that lists available wifi devices and connects to the selected on. I am using Wifi.connection of wifi package of flutter to connect to the selected network.
It returns WifiState.error everytime i try to connect to the wifi.

This is the code in which i try to connect to the wifi.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:wifi/wifi.dart';

Future<Null> connection() async {
  print('funciton called');
  Wifi.connection('Mohit1', 'mohit@123').then((v) {
    print(v);
  });
}


class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: ()=> connection(),
          child: Text('Connect'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am kinda stuck with this, as it is just a single API. i dont know what to look for regarding this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_configuration#-readme-tab- use this

Comment: Thank you for responding! i had a look at this package but i didnot find any API to connect to a wifi, though it has APIs to tell whether it is connected or not (bool).

I got it working with wifi dart package, but sometimes it requires forgetting the wifi to make it login successfully. I am not sure when exactly it needs wifi to be forgotten but once it stuck, it works on forgetting the wifi and running the code again.

It would be helpful if you could help out in the exact use case: when wifi needs to be forgotten and in that case it shows(WifiState.Error). Else it is working fine now.

Comment: i will see give me some time

Comment: In my case I get that error ALL the time! And that plugin never get updated since Mar 4, 2019! Almost 2 years now!!!!

Comment: I think i got the use case: Whenever i delete the app and install it again on my device, wifi needs to be forgotten to get it working, else if i update the app it works fine without forgetting the wifi. Still dont know how to rectify it and automate its working to change or delete any data while installing so as to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

The [wifi](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi) package seems to be not updated for a long time now. The [flutter_wifi_connect](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_wifi_connect) and [wifi_iot](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_iot) should be capable what you needed.